# Can servers block curl requests?

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I am working on ZOHO API and trying to update the record using cURL. I tried different cURL variations, but it always returns "false". But when I call the same URL using a browser, it works.

Is there any way they can block cURL requests? Is there any other way I can call that URL using a POST or maybe a GET request?

The cURL code I have tried is as below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Servers cannot block cURL requests per se, but they can block any request that they do not like. If the server checks for some parameters that your cURL request does not satisfy, it could decide to respond differently.

In the vast majority of cases, this difference in behavior is triggered by the presence (or absence) and values of the HTTP request headers. For example, the server might check that the `User-Agent` header is present and has a valid value (it could also check lots of other things).

To find out what the HTTP request coming from the browser looks like, use an HTTP debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or your browser's developer tools.

To add your own headers to your cURL request, use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('HeaderName: HeaderValue'));
```

Comment: Agree with ur statement "parameters that your curl request does not satisfy" but in there official documentation, they didnt mentioned anything such. One more thing, there API has to be called over HTTPS....CURL manages internally or do i have to add something more to deal with HTTPS  ?

Comment: @AmitPatil: Yes, curl does HTTPS. Can't really speak about the ZOHO API, I 've never even looked at it.

Comment: *"In the vast majority of cases, this difference in behavior is triggered by the presence (or absence) and values of the HTTP request headers"* Modern request forges blockers are much smarter than that nowadays, imho.

Comment: @TomDesp: I 'd very much like to read more details on that, especially considering that we 're talking about an API (which means that legitimate requests cannot really be expected to "look human" by *any* criteria).

Comment: @Jon: I **totally agree** with you considering the API perspective. I'm just saying that headers are not always sufficient. For instance, I already had to enable cookie jars for enabling redirections with temporary tokens sent by the server, stored in the cookies and passed to the redirected location (`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER`). Anyway, that's the solution I found to the headers-are-not-enough issues I encountered. There may be simpler solutions.

Comment: @TomDesp: Cookies are also passed on as HTTP headers though. ;-)

Comment: Guys TomDesp & Jon : i got a solution....added "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" and it worked...There is "invalid data error" from zoho server....but atleast my request has been heard by server...many thanks for looking in to it

Comment: @Jon: passed to server via headers for sure. But at least you have to tell cUrl to store them while being redirected, right?

Comment: Cna you provide with the example of array('Headername: HeaderValue')? what shoud go inside the array

Comment: Agree. It is mostly the `user-agent`.

Answer (score 23):

Many web servers want to block HTTP requests forged by something else than a browser, to prevent bots abuses.
If you want to simulate/pretend your request from a browser, you at least have to:

1. Pass the exact same headers than your browsers (use ie [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) to get them)

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   ```
2. Change the user agent (name of the browser)

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
   ```
3. Enable cookies (for eg redirection and session handling)

   ```
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   ```
4. Add referers

   ```
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
   ```

And pray you haven't missed anything!

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question *"Is there any way they can block CURL requests?"*: Yes, in fact one may detect a cURL request by reading the `User-Agent` header.

You can change the user agent by calling `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My user agent string!');`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate a little more on this, you can use the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');  or something like that to fake the user agent. In this case, the server would think a Firefox browser was making the request.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).