# PHP parser blocked

Tags: php, parsing, curl

Has anyone had issues with trying to contents from a website and it comes up with a security message blocking you? I tried first with get_file_contents and that was blocked....so I tried using CURL:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URLhttp);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $page = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

ERROR I get:

```
  The page you are attempting to access is unable to be served.
  Why has this happened?

Our security systems have detected unusual patterns of behaviour relating to the processing of this request.
This could be because some element of the request submitted by your browser has activated one of the filters we use to protect Rightmove from malicious requests (i.e. attempts to 'hack' the site).
Alternatively it could be because your IP address is sending an unusually high amount of requests to Rightmove; this could either be from your browser or from other browsers that share the same internet proxy (this kind of setup is common in office environments).
```

Is it possible that some websites can just block you entirely? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Well obvious it is possible to block you entirely since it's happening to you, and no, SO is not the place to learn how to circumvent such security measures.

Comment: Check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391137/can-servers-block-curl-requests

Comment: Thanks a lot mitkosoft, looks like some good information. I'm not actually trying to do anything illegal or even scraping....I was just playing around trying to learn PHP and came across that error. So thanks for the additional info