# Curl cannot get the redirected contents

Tags: php, curl, redirect

I try to use curl to get the contents of a redirected URL, as below:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.datanumen.com/ko/blogs/blogs/sql-server-database-mirroring-technique-advantages-disadvantages/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$retry_count = 2;

do
{
    
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$header_size = $response_info['header_size'];
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$html = substr($response, $header_size);

$has_valid_contents = (stripos($html, '<body') !== false);

if (!$has_valid_contents)   {
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs.txt', 'invalid content'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
else
{
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs.txt', 'valid content'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); 
}
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs.txt', '$response: '.$response.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); 

$retry_count--;

} while (($retry_count > 0) and !$has_valid_contents);
    
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But the result is always "invalid contents".

The response will only contain the header, not the html page, look like below:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Fri, 22 Dec 2023 15:39:16 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
cf-ray: 839974e25a740fd3-LAX
cf-cache-status: EXPIRED
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-age=2592000
expires: Sun, 21 Jan 2024 15:29:25 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 22 Dec 2023 15:32:03 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
vary: Accept-Encoding
cdn-cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
cdn-cache-control: max-age=1209600
cf-apo-via: origin,miss
referrer-policy: no-referrer, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-proxy-cache: HIT
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=33rR2drY03Q3%2FEpGeMEhTErf%2BxrE%2FZGPlksUPxbZt7BZrq4E68RYsEufuFJLIw8l3%2Fz5LLqxk3%2FXI6vU6tGrRk2%2BRV7CjR9OwHIILLTwFc5sty%2FxcMg0bqjOJBIr2XTBhVp5"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
```

I check some existing questions, such as [cURL get redirect url content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128983/curl-get-redirect-url-content), but cannot find a solution

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  What does `$response` look like? `CURLOPT_HEADER, 0` should mean no headers, so what is the header stuff doing, have you looked at `$header`?  How about `$html`, have you checked what it is?  You shouldn't have to do any gzipping, [curl does that automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364640/how-to-properly-handle-a-gzipped-page-when-using-curl), just like any http client, so what is that stuff doing?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you for your advice, I have fixed the issues. Anyway, they will not affect the final results as I check the html contents of the page. The response will contain only the headers, not the html contents if it is a redirection. For normal pages, it will contain the valid html contents.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The title of your question is "*get the redirected contents*", but in your comment you're talking about headers.  Do you want content, or headers, or both?  Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135574/6089612) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request), which specifically deals with redirects?